# Token to output the last value in a multi-value field?

Tags: entities, rules, tokens

I have a text field in an Entityform set to accept an unlimited number of values:

[image]

I'm trying to build a Rule that sends an email with the text from the last submitted value from the field. The token that I have to work with is:

`[entityform:field-some-text]`

The output of this token just concatenates all of the field's values into one text blob. For example, if I had four values, the output would look like this:

> First text value., Another bit of text., Yet another value., I enjoy donuts.

All I want is that last value, "I enjoy donuts."

Is there a different token (or something I can tack onto the token) to only output the last value? Something like:

`[entityform:field-some-text:last-value]`

---

If it makes any difference, this on a Drupal 7 site.

Comment: You might have to just implement one using a custom token. See here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1308488 there are links and example code in the comments.

Comment: There is an issue about this, [Need to figure out how to create nested tokens from the array token type](https://www.drupal.org/project/token/issues/1195874) try applying the [patch in #20](https://www.drupal.org/files/token.list-of-type.1195874.20.patch) and hopefully that will allow you to do `[entityform:field-some-text:last]`